# WPF Binding to dictionary with x:Name as a key

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Please correct my question if it's not clear. What I'm looking for is..

Here's a sample binding for a dictionary... it works:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyDictionary[ThisIsKeyInMyDict]}" />
```

I'm looking for:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Id" Text="{Binding Path=MyDictionary[x:Name]}" />
```

You see? I want to look in dictionary for a key, the same as "Name" of this control.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried `Text="{Binding Path=MyDictionary[x&#58;Name]}"` ? Colon is a special character, and may need to be escaped.

Comment: My code smell senses are tingling... This is an X/Y problem.  You've got a goal, but the method you're trying to use is incorrect/harder to use than the recommended pattern.  Binding against a dictionary is part of the code smell (ugh, no pls).  If you [edit] and give a clear description of what you are trying to do, you'll probably get a better answer.  And if you create an absolutely stripped down barebones prototype application demonstrating what you're trying to do ([mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), you'll get the best of answers.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the suggestion! I asked a little bit more complex question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43006104/7727517 The scope in this question was to narrow to add more details here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a MultiBinding for it:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <local:DictValueConverter x:Key="dictValCnv"/>        
    </Window.Resources>
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource dictValCnv}">
        <Binding Path="MyDictionary"/>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Name"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>


using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;
public class DictValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values==null || values.Length<2 )
        {
            return false;
        }

        var dict = values[0] as IDictionary;
        if(dict.Contains(values[1]))
    {
        return dict[values[1]];
    }
        return "KeyNotFound";
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```