# WPF DataTemplate binding parameter in Window.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm creating a datagrid, with filters in the column headers. It works, but I don't think it's a good approach. Let me show you the code, very simple example:

**The View**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDataGridApp.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:TestDataGridApp.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridHeader">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding DataContext.FilterName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="60" MinWidth="60" MaxWidth="60" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="60" MinWidth="60" MaxWidth="60" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**ViewModel**

```
namespace TestDataGridApp.ViewModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using TestDataGridApp.Entities;
    using Prism.Mvvm;
    public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private string _filterId;
        private string _filterName;
        private ObservableCollection<Item> _items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i)
            {
                Items.Add(new Item() {Id = i, Name = $"Item{i}"});
            }
        }
        public string FilterId
        {
            get { return _filterId; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _filterId, value);
                TriggerFilters();
            }
        }
        public string FilterName
        {
            get { return _filterName; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _filterName, value);
                TriggerFilters();
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _items, value); }
        }
        public ICollectionView ItemCollection => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Items);

        private void TriggerFilters()
        {
            ItemCollection.Filter = o => FilterItem((Item)o);
        }
        private bool FilterItem(Item item)
        {
            try
            {
                bool checkId = false;
                bool checkName = false;

                int itemId = 0;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterId) && int.TryParse(FilterId, out itemId)) checkId = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterName)) checkName = true;

                if (!checkId && !checkName) return true;
                if (item == null) return false;

                bool checkIdIsOk = (checkId && item.Id == int.Parse(FilterId) || !checkId);
                bool checkNameIsOk = (checkName && item.Name.ToUpper().Contains(FilterName.ToUpper()) || !checkName);
                if (checkIdIsOk && checkNameIsOk) return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Basically simple datagrid, 2 columns. In each column there is a `TextBox` with binded filter. Each filter has its own field, so after the focus is lost, I can filter the grid by all filters.

My issue is.. I have a lot of columns. This is customized datagrid, so you can add and remove columns on the fly and there's a lot of duplicated code. Basically this is duplicated:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
                            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                                     Text="{Binding DataContext.FilterId, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

... only this `<TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding DataContext.FilterId, ...` is changing for different columns.

So, I thought, I can easily replace it with this solution, but now.. I lost binding to my filter fields in the ViewModel:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridHeader">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding DataContext.FilterName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=Id}" Width="60" MinWidth="60" MaxWidth="60" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="60" MinWidth="60" MaxWidth="60" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeader}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

SOO.. I was thinking, to create a `Dictionary` for filters, where key would be the name of the column and in value I will store current filter (or null, if there's no  filter at the moment for this column). Something like..

```
<TextBox x:Name="Foo" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding DataContext.FiltersDictionary[Foo], RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

But then I have to Biding contexts.. for one TextBox. I'm really not sure about this solution..

**My question will be, how to create a parameter for DataTemplate in the above scenario?**

Thanks for help!

PS. It's not a duplicate. This question is about "how to create a parameter for DataTemplate". The "duplicated" question is about dictionary as a binding - a potential solution for this question.. although probably NOT. As another user suggested there might be totally different, better solution to solve this problem. Two different things. I'm shocked that I have to explain this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Binding to dictionary with x:Name as a key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987402/wpf-binding-to-dictionary-with-xname-as-a-key)

Comment: @Rekshino are you serious? it's not a duplicate. Here I'm asking "how to create a parameter for DataTemplate" and the other question is about  "dictionary as a binding". The answer to this question may have nothing to do with a dictionary at all . Did you even read those two questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to not rely only on xaml and add some code to help. For example use `Loaded` event of your `TextBox` like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridHeader">
    <DockPanel>
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Loaded="OnFilterBoxLoaded" />
    </DockPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

And setup binding when it is loaded:

```
private void OnFilterBoxLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    // find column
    DataGridColumnHeader parent = null;
    DependencyObject current = tb;
    do {
        current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
        parent = current as DataGridColumnHeader;
    }
    while (parent == null);
    // setup binding
    var binding = new Binding();
    // use parent column header as name of the filter property
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("DataContext.Filter" + parent.Column.Header);
    binding.Source = this;
    binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus;
    tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
}
```

You can use attached property to achieve the same, but I don't think it's needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that approach. But that could work! Although, I probably can't use `parent.Column.Header`, because it may contains spaces, parenthesis etc..

Comment: Well it definetely will work because I tested it before posting :) As for header - you can use any other property (Binding path maybe) or create attached property and use it for grid column to provide explicit filter name. I can post an example if you have some troubles with using attached property for this.

Comment: why attached property? I used your solution but with simple `DependencyProperty` I posted this as an answer. Can you comment if this is correct? It works.. I just don't understand why attached property?

Comment: @LouisaBickley Yes this is correct too. I was thinking about attached property because with them you can extend default classes with additional metadata (like extending DataGridColumn with filter name). In your case you can indeed just inherit from column and that is not worse (and even better) than using attached property.

Answer (score 1):

I used Evk solution with `DependencyProperty` instead of using `Header`

```
<controls:FilterDataGridTextColumn FilterName="Name" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}" />
```

FilterDataGridTextColumn :

```
public class FilterDataGridTextColumn : DataGridTextColumn
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FilterName", typeof(string), typeof(FilterDataGridTextColumn));

    public string FilterName
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(FilterNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FilterNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```