# In WPF XAML, how can I dynamically create a two-way binding to an indexed property?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a DataTemplate to define a cell template that is used in a DevExpress GridControl.  I want to create a **two-way** binding between a Dictionary property and the EditValue property of a TextEdit control.  The DataTemplate I am using is defined as:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GasValueColumnTemplate">
    <ContentControl>
        <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).FieldName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Header="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
            Width="{Binding Path=(dxci:DependencyObjectExtensions.DataContext).Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <dxe:TextEdit
                        EditValue="{Binding Path=RowData.Row.GasValueDictionary[Column.Header].Quantity}">
                     </dxe:TextEdit>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
    </ContentControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

The **Path** part of the binding specifies the GasValueDictionary, and the index value of "Column.Header" is the displayed name of the column, and is also the Key value for the desired dictionary object property.
The issue is that the **Column.Header** value is not evaluated and I get a Key Not Found error.  Of course, if I specify a hardcoded string for the index value that is also a key in the dictionary, everything works fine.

My question is then, how can I specify in XAML, an index value for the dictionary that must be evaluated at run-time?

Thanks in advance!

In response to Freggar, I modified the TextEdit declaration seen above to appear as follows:

```
   <dxe:TextEdit>
       <dxe:TextEdit.EditValue>
           <MultiBinding Converter="{converters:DictionaryValueConverter}" >
               <Binding Path="RowData.Row"/>
               <Binding Path="Column.Header"/>
           </MultiBinding>
       </dxe:TextEdit.EditValue>
    </dxe:TextEdit>
```

It works fine for retrieving data from the dictionary.  As the TextEdit has Two-Way binding, the ConvertBack function fails to properly update the dictionary if the EditValue is modified.

Comment: A converter is probably your best bet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100690/binding-in-wpf-to-element-of-array-specified-by-property

Comment: Is this [WPF Binding to dictionary with x:Name as a key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42987402/7713750) that, what you are looking for?

Comment: You may want to refactor this code to use a view model; I've never seen anyone index into a dictionary for databinding.

Comment: I modified the description above to include using a converter.  The converter works  fine for fetching data from the dictionary, but fails to properly update the dictionary if the value is changed in the TextEdit control.  I'm still looking into that.